# What will be the 100th term of the series:

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n+1}-3a_n+2=4n$ for every positive integer n, then find the value of $a_{100}$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I tried working back from $a_{100}$ to $a_1$, hoping it expresses out as 2/3 different series which can be then solved to get the solution.
But that is a very convoluted approach. There should be simpler method. It's supposed to be solved in 3-4 mins.

Comment: Can you find an explicit expression for $a_{n+2}$?

Comment: Hint. You should find $3^{100}-200$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT : $$a_{n+1}-3a_n+2=4n$$
$$\Rightarrow a_{n+1}+2n+2=3a_n+6n$$
$$\Rightarrow a_{n+1}+2(n+1)=3(a_n+2n)$$
Now setting $b_n=a_n+2n$ gives 
$$b_{n+1}=3b_n.$$

Comment: ahh! I was going in the direction of $a_{n+1} + (n+1) + 1 = 3 (a_n + n)$

That was nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $a_m=c_m+Am^2+Bm+C$

$4n-2=a_{n+1}-3a_n=c_{n+1}-3c_n+A(2n+1)+B=c_{n+1}-3c_n+2An+A+B$

Set $2A=4,A+B=-2$ to get $c_{n+1}=3c_n$